# Nil Coalescing returning nil instead of default value when parsing JSON

Tags: json, swift

Im parsing JSON and I'm having an issue when i use nil coalescing to try and return a default value for a key / value set that sometimes doesn't exist. The website I'm parsing json from is http://heroesjson.com .  The creator has even given me a map of how to parse it. Where I run into problems is when I try to parse the talents key. Not every talent has a "cooldown" or "prerequisite" key. SO I tried to use nil coalescing to assign a default value if the key/value set doesn't exist BUT when I try to assign the value to iCooldown or sPrerequisite, i get the error unexpectedly found nil when trying to unwrap optional. How can that be since I gave it a default value?

```
//Parse Talent Class
                        if let talentsArray = dict[x]["talents"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                            for y in 0 ..< dict.count {
                                if let allHeroTalents = talentsArray["\(y)"]{
                                    for z in 0 ..< allHeroTalents.count {


                                            let id = allHeroTalents[z]["id"]
                                            let name = allHeroTalents[z]["name"]
                                            let description = allHeroTalents[z]["description"]
                                            let cooldown = allHeroTalents[z]["cooldown"] ?? 0.0
                                            let prerequisite = allHeroTalents[z]["prerequisite"] ?? ""
                                            let icon = allHeroTalents[z]["icon"]


                                            let sId = id as? String
                                            let sName = name as? String
                                            let sDescription = description as? String
                                            //let iCooldown = cooldown as! Double
                                            //let sPrerequisite = prerequisite as! String
                                            let sIcon = icon as? String
                                            //let talent = Talent(id: sId!, name: sName!, description: sDescription!, cooldown: iCooldown, prerequisite: sPrerequisite, icon: sIcon!)
                                        print("\(hero.name) has talent \(cooldown)")


                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
```

I have included the whole file below for reference. My main file just calls func parseData().

```html
import Foundation



class Hero {

    var id: String?
    var attributeid: String?
    var name: String?
    var title: String?
    var description: String?
    var role: String?
    var type: String?
    var gender: String?
    var franchise: String?
    var difficulty: String?
    var icon: String?
    var ratings: Ratings?
    var stats: Stats?
    var talents: [Talent]?
    
    
  
    
    
    init(id: String, attributeid: String, name: String, title: String, description: String, role: String, type: String, gender: String, franchise: String, difficulty: String, icon: String){
        self.id = id
        self.attributeid = attributeid
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.role = role
        self.type = type
        self.gender = gender
        self.franchise = franchise
        self.difficulty = difficulty
        self.icon = icon

        
    }
    
}


class Ratings {
    var damage: Int?
    var utility: Int?
    var survivability: Int?
    var complexity: Int?
    
    
    init(damage: Int, utility: Int, survivability: Int, complexity: Int) {
        self.damage = damage
        self.utility = utility
        self.survivability = survivability
        self.complexity = complexity
    }
}

class Stats {
    var hp: Int?
    var hpPerLevel: Int?
    var hpRegen: Double?
    var hpRegenPerLevel: Double?
    var mana: Int?
    var manaPerLevel: Int?
    var manaRegen: Double?
    var manaRegenPerLevel: Double?
   
    
    init(hp: Int, hpPerLevel: Int, hpRegen: Double, hpRegenPerLevel: Double, mana: Int, manaPerLevel: Int, manaRegen: Double, manaRegenPerLevel: Double) {
        self.hp = hp
        self.hpPerLevel = hpPerLevel
        self.hpRegen = hpRegen
        self.hpRegenPerLevel = hpRegenPerLevel
        self.mana = mana
        self.manaPerLevel = manaPerLevel
        self.manaRegen = manaRegen
        self.manaRegenPerLevel = manaRegenPerLevel
    }
    
    
}

class Talent {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var description: String?
    var cooldown: Double?
    var prerequisite: String?
    var icon: String?
   

    
    init(id: String, name: String, description: String, cooldown: Double, prerequisite: String, icon: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.cooldown = cooldown
        self.prerequisite = prerequisite
        self.icon = icon
        
    }
    
    
}

class Ability {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var description: String?
    var shortcut: String?
    var cooldown: Double?
    var manaCost: Double?
    var manaCostPerSecond: Double?
    var aimType: String?
    var heroic: Bool?
    var trait: Bool?
    var mount: Bool?
    var icon: String?
    
    init(id: String, name: String, description: String, shortcut: String, cooldown: Double, manaCost: Double, manaCostPerSecond: Double, aimType: String, heroic: Bool, trait: Bool, mount: Bool, icon: String){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.shortcut = shortcut
        self.cooldown = cooldown
        self.manaCost = manaCost
        self.manaCostPerSecond = manaCostPerSecond
        self.aimType = aimType
        self.heroic = heroic
        self.trait = trait
        self.mount = mount
        self.icon = icon

    }
    
}

func parseData(){
    let urlString = "http://heroesjson.com/heroes.json"
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    
    session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        
        if let responseData = data {
            
            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
                
                if let dict = json as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                    for x in 0 ..< dict.count {
                        
                        
                        if let id = dict[x]["id"], let attributeid = dict[x]["attributeid"], let name = dict[x]["name"], let title = dict[x]["title"], let description = dict[x]["description"], let role = dict[x]["role"], let type = dict[x]["type"], let gender = dict[x]["gender"], let franchise = dict[x]["franchise"], let difficulty = dict[x]["difficulty"], let icon = dict[x]["icon"] {
                            
                            let hero = Hero(id: id as! String, attributeid: attributeid as! String, name: name as! String, title: title as! String, description: description as! String, role: role as! String, type: type as! String, gender: gender as! String, franchise: franchise as! String, difficulty: difficulty as! String, icon: icon as! String)
                            
                             // Parse Ratings Class
                            
                            if let dataArray = dict[x]["ratings"] as? Dictionary<String, Int> {
                                
                                if let damage = dataArray["damage"], let utility = dataArray["utility"], let survivability = dataArray["damage"], let complexity = dataArray["complexity"] {
                                    
                                    let rating = Ratings(damage: damage , utility: utility , survivability: survivability , complexity: complexity )
                                    hero.ratings = rating
                                    //print("\(hero.name) has a damage rating of \(hero.ratings!.damage)")
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            
                            //Parse Stats Class
                            if let statsArray = dict[x]["stats"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                

                                if let dummy = statsArray[hero.id!]{//error handleing for vikings
                                    
                                    
                                    if let hp = statsArray[hero.id!]!["hp"], let hpPerLevel = statsArray[hero.id!]!["hpPerLevel"], let hpRegen = statsArray[hero.id!]!["hpRegen"], let hpRegenPerLevel = statsArray[hero.id!]!["hpRegenPerLevel"], let mana = statsArray[hero.id!]!["mana"], let manaPerLevel = statsArray[hero.id!]!["manaPerLevel"], let manaRegen = statsArray[hero.id!]!["manaRegen"], let manaRegenPerLevel = statsArray[hero.id!]!["manaRegenPerLevel"] {
                                        
                                        
                                        let stats = Stats(hp: hp as! Int, hpPerLevel: hpPerLevel as! Int, hpRegen: hpRegen as! Double, hpRegenPerLevel: hpRegenPerLevel as! Double, mana: mana as! Int, manaPerLevel: manaPerLevel as! Int, manaRegen: manaRegen as! Double, manaRegenPerLevel: manaRegenPerLevel as! Double)
                                        
                                        
                                        hero.stats = stats
                                    }
                                    
                                }//closes let dummy
                                
                                
                            }
                            
                            //Parse Talent Class
                            if let talentsArray = dict[x]["talents"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                
                                for y in 0 ..< dict.count {
                                    if let allHeroTalents = talentsArray["\(y)"]{
                                        for z in 0 ..< allHeroTalents.count {

                                            
                                                let id = allHeroTalents[z]["id"]
                                                let name = allHeroTalents[z]["name"]
                                                let description = allHeroTalents[z]["description"]
                                                let cooldown = allHeroTalents[z]["cooldown"] ?? 0.0
                                                let prerequisite = allHeroTalents[z]["prerequisite"] ?? ""
                                                let icon = allHeroTalents[z]["icon"]
                                            
                                            
                                                let sId = id as? String
                                                let sName = name as? String
                                                let sDescription = description as? String
                                                //let iCooldown = cooldown as! Double
                                                //let sPrerequisite = prerequisite as! String
                                                let sIcon = icon as? String
                                                //let talent = Talent(id: sId!, name: sName!, description: sDescription!, cooldown: iCooldown, prerequisite: sPrerequisite, icon: sIcon!)
                                            print("\(hero.name) has talent \(cooldown)")
                                            
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }
                            
                            // Parse Ability Class

                            if let abilitiesArray = dict[x]["abilities"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                for c in 0 ..< abilitiesArray.count {
                                   
                                    for d in 0 ..< abilitiesArray.count {
                                        
                                    if let dummy = abilitiesArray[hero.id!]{
                                        
                                            
                                            let id = abilitiesArray[hero.id!]!["id"]
                                            let name = abilitiesArray[hero.id!]!["name"]
                                            let description = abilitiesArray[hero.id!]!["description"]
                                            let shortcut = abilitiesArray[hero.id!]!["shortcut"]
                                            let cooldown = abilitiesArray[hero.id!]!["cooldown"]
                                            let manaCost = abilitiesArray[hero.id!]!["manaCost"]
                                            let manaCostPerSecond = abilitiesArray[hero.id!]!["manaCostPerSecond"]
                                            let aimType = abilitiesArray[hero.id!]!["aimType"]
                                            let heroic = abilitiesArray[hero.id!]!["heroic"]
                                            let trait = abilitiesArray[hero.id!]!["trait"]
                                            let mount = abilitiesArray[hero.id!]!["mount"]
                                            let icon = abilitiesArray[hero.id!]!["icon"]

                                            
                                            let sId = id as? String
                                            let sName = name as? String
                                            let sDescription = description as? String
                                            let sShortcut = shortcut as? String
                                            let sCooldown = cooldown as? Double
                                            let sManaCost = manaCost as? Double
                                            let sManaCostPerSecond = manaCostPerSecond as? Double
                                            let sAimType = aimType as? String
                                            let sHeroic = heroic as? Bool
                                            let sTrait = trait as? Bool
                                            let sMount = mount as? Bool
                                            let sIcon = icon as? String
                                            
                                            
//                                            let abilities = Ability(id: sId!, name: sName!, description: sDescription!, shortcut: sShortcut!, cooldown: sCooldown!, manaCost: sManaCost!, manaCostPerSecond: sManaCostPerSecond!, aimType: sAimType!, heroic: sHeroic!, trait: sTrait!, mount: sMount!, icon: sIcon!)
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                }
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            }
                            
                            
                            heroes.append(hero)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("Could not serialize")
            }
        }
        
        
        }.resume()
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: May I suggest a few things: Your parse data function is getting pretty chunky. I would suggest extracting out the `Dictionary` to object conversion into initializers. For example give `Ability` an initializer that takes a `[String: Any]` parameter, and automatically assigns the members appropriately. This will also make it much easier to make changes to those data classes, because you can add a member, and add its assignment in the initializer, without hunting around your parseData and other functions

Comment: Furthermore, all your Class members are optional and `var` variable. A lot of them seem like they can be non-optional and `let` constants.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Could you give me an example of how I would do that (give Ability an initializer that takes a [String: Any] parameter, and automatically assigns the members appropriately) ? I'm new to coding and didn't even know that was possible.

Comment: Take a look at my take on the [`Talent` class here](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57bb05a40dcf4abf47da286a). Notice a few things: **1)** I made this into a struct, as they're generally easier to work with, and also more performant. **2)** I made all the `var` variables into `let` constants. Feel free to change them back, but only do so when you *need* to be able to change them. **3)** I changed the members to not be optionals, because they don't seem to need to be.

Comment: This way, you seperate apart your initilization logic into smaller parts, rather than one monolithic `parseData` function that spans over dozens of lines.

Comment: Thank for the example and explanation. I am having trouble implementing it though because we have omitted a part of the code that is necessary. The nil coalescing operator. let prerequisite = item["prerequisite"]! ?? "".  I don't know where I would insert this in your code example because essentially it skips this part by allowing the dictionary to go directly to initialization. By the way I finally got the nil coalescing operator to work and it solved ALL of my problems. All it needed was a !.

Comment: Why are you using null coalescence at all? Storing `0` or `""` as default values is bad practice, because Swift gives you a better way (you could just store a `nil` into an optional value.). If you did need it however, you would simply insert it after the dictionary value you want to effect, before it gets passed as a param into the other init

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Its not that I need them necessarily, but I don't know how to initialize without them. Sometimes cooldown / prerequisite don't even show up as keys in the dictionary I'm taking the rest of the information from.  So when I initialize without them I have errors. When cooldown / prerequisite do show up as keys I need to store them. How would you suggest I solve this problem?  I feel like I should have just asked to see how some people would parse that whole json file. It shouldn't be too hard with my classes already created. I can also post my entire working code in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121565/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-apple).

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I'm trying to communicate with you in chat but something happened and it won't let me chat even though I have enough Reputation. I guess I lost some rep and then gained some rep and the system hasn't updated. I can still read your messages in chat though so if you post your email or another preferred method of communicating we can continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but it seems that you are using your Dictionary as an Array. which causes you to unwrap optional values that are not there.

From your code:

```
//- talentsArray is a dictionary! 
if let talentsArray = dict[x]["talents"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    for y in 0 ..< dict.count {
        //- talentsArray["\(y)"] y is a value from 0 to the count, not necesarilly a key.
        if let allHeroTalents = talentsArray["\(y)"]{
            for z in 0 ..< allHeroTalents.count {
              // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dictionaries do not maintain order, if you need to iterate through them you can Enumerate your dictionary, you have to use the `for (key, value) in dictionary` syntax. Something along the lines of:

```
if let talents = dict[x]["talents"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    for (index, talent) in talents {
        for attribute in talent {
           // Do your thing.
        }
    }
}
```

Your problem as I understand it, is not the coalescing, but the incorrect use of the dictionary DS. I replicated the API call and can see that even if you where to iterate through it while treating the index as the key of the dictionary, you'll run into some trouble as the keys are in no way sequential:

[image]

**UPDATE**

As I mentioned in the comments, while your solution works `let cooldown = item[cooldown]!` will force unwrap your optional, which is not the best approach when dealing with optional values fetched from an API (Specially if they are not always included in the data as you mention in the original question). Assuming that your 'cooldown' is a double and 'prerequisite' is a string, I would implement it like this:

```
let cooldown = item["cooldown"] as? Double ?? 0.00
let prerequisite = item["prerequisite"] as? String ?? ""
```

This approach will unwrap your optional while casting to the correct expected type, and then coalesce the value of the key value pair. This approach is much safer as it does not assume that the API Call will contain these keys.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You should add a part about not needing to iterate over a dictionary if you're just looking for a particular key

Comment: Although this did help me access my data easier it did not solve my issue. I did implement you suggestions and they did help. The nil coalescing operator needed a ! and that fixed everything. let prerequisite = item["prerequisite"]! ?? "".

Comment: Hello, I'm glad it helped, I'd like to suggest however that force unwrapping your optional is not a good idea, do you understand why is working now? When you access a member of your dictionary ie 'let cooldown = item[cooldown]!' You are telling swift that you are 100% sure that your dictionary contains a member that has the key 'cooldown'. But what happens if the Api changes? Or if the hero you are getting does not have that member? Your application will fail and you will get a 'found nil while unwrapping your optional' which defeats the purpose of nil coalescing.

Comment: I'll update my answer with what I think should be the right approach.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled across the answer by messing with my code. Apparently all I needed to do was unwrap (use !) the variable going into the nil coalescing operator.

```
let cooldown = item["cooldown"]! ?? 0.00
let prerequisite = item["prerequisite"]! ?? ""
```

Entire Working Code

```html
import Foundation



class Hero {

    var id: String?
    var attributeid: String?
    var name: String?
    var title: String?
    var description: String?
    var role: String?
    var type: String?
    var gender: String?
    var franchise: String?
    var difficulty: String?
    var icon: String?
    var ratings: Ratings?
    var stats: Stats?
    var talents: [String: [Talent]]?
    var abilities: [String: [Ability]]?
    
    
  
    
    
    init(id: String, attributeid: String, name: String, title: String, description: String, role: String, type: String, gender: String, franchise: String, difficulty: String, icon: String){
        self.id = id
        self.attributeid = attributeid
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.role = role
        self.type = type
        self.gender = gender
        self.franchise = franchise
        self.difficulty = difficulty
        self.icon = icon

        
    }
    
}


class Ratings {
    var damage: Int?
    var utility: Int?
    var survivability: Int?
    var complexity: Int?
    
    
    init(damage: Int, utility: Int, survivability: Int, complexity: Int) {
        self.damage = damage
        self.utility = utility
        self.survivability = survivability
        self.complexity = complexity
    }
}

class Stats {
    var hp: Int?
    var hpPerLevel: Int?
    var hpRegen: Double?
    var hpRegenPerLevel: Double?
    var mana: Int?
    var manaPerLevel: Int?
    var manaRegen: Double?
    var manaRegenPerLevel: Double?
   
    
    init(hp: Int, hpPerLevel: Int, hpRegen: Double, hpRegenPerLevel: Double, mana: Int, manaPerLevel: Int, manaRegen: Double, manaRegenPerLevel: Double) {
        self.hp = hp
        self.hpPerLevel = hpPerLevel
        self.hpRegen = hpRegen
        self.hpRegenPerLevel = hpRegenPerLevel
        self.mana = mana
        self.manaPerLevel = manaPerLevel
        self.manaRegen = manaRegen
        self.manaRegenPerLevel = manaRegenPerLevel
    }
    
    
}

class Talent {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var description: String?
    var cooldown: Double?
    var prerequisite: String?
    var icon: String?
   

    
    init(id: String, name: String, description: String, cooldown: Double, prerequisite: String, icon: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.cooldown = cooldown
        self.prerequisite = prerequisite
        self.icon = icon
    }
    
    
}

class Ability {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var description: String?
    var shortcut: String?
    var cooldown: Double?
    var manaCost: Double?
    var manaCostPerSecond: Double?
    var aimType: String?
    var heroic: Bool?
    var trait: Bool?
    var mount: Bool?
    var icon: String?
    
    init(id: String, name: String, description: String, shortcut: String, cooldown: Double, manaCost: Double, manaCostPerSecond: Double, aimType: String, heroic: Bool, trait: Bool, mount: Bool, icon: String){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.shortcut = shortcut
        self.cooldown = cooldown
        self.manaCost = manaCost
        self.manaCostPerSecond = manaCostPerSecond
        self.aimType = aimType
        self.heroic = heroic
        self.trait = trait
        self.mount = mount
        self.icon = icon

    }
    
}

func parseData() {
    let urlString = "http://heroesjson.com/heroes.json"
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    
    session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        
        if let responseData = data {
            
            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
                
                if let dict = json as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                    for x in 0 ..< dict.count {
                        
                        
                        if let id = dict[x]["id"], let attributeid = dict[x]["attributeid"], let name = dict[x]["name"], let title = dict[x]["title"], let description = dict[x]["description"], let role = dict[x]["role"], let type = dict[x]["type"], let gender = dict[x]["gender"], let franchise = dict[x]["franchise"], let difficulty = dict[x]["difficulty"], let icon = dict[x]["icon"] {
                            
                            let hero = Hero(id: id as! String, attributeid: attributeid as! String, name: name as! String, title: title as! String, description: description as! String, role: role as! String, type: type as! String, gender: gender as! String, franchise: franchise as! String, difficulty: difficulty as! String, icon: icon as! String)
                            
                             // Parse Ratings Class
                            
                            if let dataArray = dict[x]["ratings"] as? Dictionary<String, Int> {
                                
                                if let damage = dataArray["damage"], let utility = dataArray["utility"], let survivability = dataArray["damage"], let complexity = dataArray["complexity"] {
                                    
                                    let rating = Ratings(damage: damage , utility: utility , survivability: survivability , complexity: complexity )
                                    hero.ratings = rating
                                    //print("\(hero.name) has a damage rating of \(hero.ratings!.damage)")
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            
                            //Parse Stats Class
                            if let statsArray = dict[x]["stats"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                

                                if let dummy = statsArray[hero.id!]{//error handleing for vikings - parsing without this causes errors
                                    
                                    
                                    if let hp = statsArray[hero.id!]!["hp"], let hpPerLevel = statsArray[hero.id!]!["hpPerLevel"], let hpRegen = statsArray[hero.id!]!["hpRegen"], let hpRegenPerLevel = statsArray[hero.id!]!["hpRegenPerLevel"], let mana = statsArray[hero.id!]!["mana"], let manaPerLevel = statsArray[hero.id!]!["manaPerLevel"], let manaRegen = statsArray[hero.id!]!["manaRegen"], let manaRegenPerLevel = statsArray[hero.id!]!["manaRegenPerLevel"] {
                                        
                                        
                                        let stats = Stats(hp: hp as! Int, hpPerLevel: hpPerLevel as! Int, hpRegen: hpRegen as! Double, hpRegenPerLevel: hpRegenPerLevel as! Double, mana: mana as! Int, manaPerLevel: manaPerLevel as! Int, manaRegen: manaRegen as! Double, manaRegenPerLevel: manaRegenPerLevel as! Double)
                                        
                                        
                                        hero.stats = stats
                                    }
                                    
                                }//closes let dummy
                                
                                
                            }
                            
                            //Parse Talent Class
                            
                            if let talentsDict = dict[x]["talents"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                for (index, talentsAtLevel) in talentsDict {
                                   
                                    var talents = [Talent]()
                                    
                                    for item in talentsAtLevel as! [AnyObject] {
                                    
                                        let id = item["id"]
                                        let name = item["name"]
                                        let description = item["description"]
                                        let cooldown = item["cooldown"]! ?? 0.00
                                        let prerequisite = item["prerequisite"]! ?? ""
                                        let icon = item["icon"]
                                        
                                        
                                        let sId = id as? String
                                        let sName = name as? String
                                        let sDescription = description as? String
                                        let iCooldown = cooldown as! Double
                                        let sPrerequisite = prerequisite as! String
                                        let sIcon = icon as? String
                                        let talent = Talent(id: sId!, name: sName!, description: sDescription!, cooldown: iCooldown, prerequisite: sPrerequisite, icon: sIcon!)
                                        talents.append(talent)
                                        
                                    }
                                    hero.talents = ["\(index)": talents]
                                }
                            }
                            
                            //Parse Ability Class
                            
                            if let abilitiesDict = dict[x]["abilities"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                for (index, abilitiesAtLevel) in abilitiesDict { //index = heroid
                                   
                                    var abilities = [Ability]()
                                    
                                    for item in abilitiesAtLevel as! [AnyObject] { //item = ability
                                        
                                        let id = item["id"]! ?? ""
                                        let name = item["name"]! ?? ""
                                        let description = item["description"]! ?? ""
                                        let shortcut = item["shortcut"]! ?? ""
                                        let cooldown = item["cooldown"]! ?? 0.0
                                        let manaCost = item["manaCost"]! ?? 0.0
                                        let manaCostPerSecond = item["manaCostPerSecond"]! ?? 0.0
                                        let aimType = item["aimType"]! ?? ""
                                        let heroic = item["heroic"]! ?? false
                                        let trait = item["trait"]! ?? false
                                        let mount = item["mount"]! ?? false
                                        let icon = item["icon"]! ?? ""
                                        
                                        
                                        let sId = id as? String
                                        let sName = name as? String
                                        let sDescription = description as? String
                                        let sShortcut = shortcut as? String
                                        let sCooldown = cooldown as? Double
                                        let sManaCost = manaCost as? Double
                                        let sManaCostPerSecond = manaCostPerSecond as? Double
                                        let sAimType = aimType as? String
                                        let sHeroic = heroic as? Bool
                                        let sTrait = trait as? Bool
                                        let sMount = mount as? Bool
                                        let sIcon = icon as? String
                                        let ability = Ability(id: sId!, name: sName!, description: sDescription!, shortcut: sShortcut!, cooldown: sCooldown!, manaCost: sManaCost!, manaCostPerSecond: sManaCostPerSecond!, aimType: sAimType!, heroic: sHeroic!, trait: sTrait!, mount: sMount!, icon: sIcon!)
                                        abilities.append(ability)
                                        
                                        
                                    }
                                    hero.abilities = ["\(index)": abilities]

                                }
                            }
                            
                            heroes.append(hero)
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            } catch {
                print("Could not serialize")
            }
        }
        
        }.resume()
}
```